# Variable is reset. Dont know why

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr

I have variable (option), which I display on lcd to see the value. When I pressed button it should change value to 1. But it works in other way. (option) is 1 only when I hold button, but when I release this button, the variable is 0. I searched in all files (option), but it is only in one file and all code lines with this variable is show in this piece of code (in fun (menuRun()) ).

In menu.c

```
void menuRun(char * Uline, char * Lline, uint8_t * x, uint8_t * y)
{
    uint8_t button;
    uint16_t value;
    char buffer[20];
    button = whichButton(buffer);
    value = getValue();

    if (menuX==0) /* <---- this is false when i am testing*/
    {
        cursorOn();
        if (menuY==0)
        {
            strncpy(bufferUline,"*",strlen("*"));
            strncpy(bufferLline," ",strlen(" "));
        } else
        {
            strncpy(bufferLline,"*",strlen("*"));
            strncpy(bufferUline," ",strlen(" "));
        }

        if (button == 1)
        {
            menuX = 1;
            cursorOff();
        }else if (button == 3)
        {
            menuY=0;
            strncpy(bufferUline,"*",strlen("*"));
            strncpy(bufferLline," ",strlen(" "));
        }else if (button == 4)
        {
            menuY=1;
            strncpy(bufferLline,"*",strlen("*"));
            strncpy(bufferUline," ",strlen(" "));
        }
    } else /* <---- this is true when i am testing*/
    {
        if (menuY & 1) /* <---- this is false when i am testing*/
        {
            if (option & 1)
            {
                x=6;
                strcpy(bufferLline,"      0000     ");
            }else
            {

            }
        }else /* <---- this is true when i am testing*/
        {
            /* This doesnt matter for now*/
            if (option&1)
            {
                strcpy(bufferUline,"    Nowy kod    ");
                //strcpy(bufferLline,"      xxxx     ");
            }else
            {
                strcpy(bufferUline," Nowa pora dnia ");
                //strcpy(bufferLline,"  xx:xx-xx:xx  ");
            }

            if (button == 2)
            {
                menuX=0;
                menuY=0;
            }
            else if (button == 3)
            {
                /*Here I change variable option, when button pressed*/
                option=1;
            }else if (button == 4)
            {
                //option=0;
            }

        }
    }

    //strcpy(bufferLline,itoa(option,buffer,10));

    //strncpy(bufferLline+5,itoa(menu,buffer,10),strlen(itoa(menu,buffer,10)));


    /* Here I copy value of variable "option" into bufferLline, which is display on lcd*/
    strncpy(bufferLline,itoa(option,buffer,10),strlen(itoa(option,buffer,10)));

    *x=menuX;
    *y=menuY;
    strcpy(Uline,bufferUline);
    strcpy(Lline,bufferLline);
}
```

In menu.h

```
uint8_t menuX, menuY;
uint8_t menuChoice, menu, option;
```

In main.c

```
int main(void)
{
    init();

    char buffer[11];

    correctCode = eeprom_read_word(&correctCodeEem);
    correctCode = 1234;

    counterClick=0;
    menuChoice=1;
    uint8_t x,y;
    while(1)
    {
            if (led & 1)
            {
                menuRun(upperLine,lowerLine,&x,&y);



                led=0;
            }
            if (lcd & 1)
            {
                //char upperBuffer[16], lowerBuffer[16];

                //strcpy(upperBuffer,upperLine);
                //strcpy(lowerBuffer,lowerLine);
                lcdDisplay(upperLine,lowerLine);
                lcdGoTo(x,y);
                lcd=0;
            }
    }

}
```

Flags led and lcd is set by timer and it works well.

I dont know why (option) is reset. When I pressed button once, It should set (option) to 1.

Comment: 1. There is no option variable at all in your code, 2. That's why no one should use global variables unless they really know what they're doing, if you do it just to prevent passing it as a paramter to functions, then that's the problem so please redesign your program.

Comment: 1. (option) is global variable. Why are you saying that, there isnt? 2. I have to use global variables as flags.

Comment: Is it a requirement? it's a very bad idea, if it's your idea, rethink your program, global variables are very dangerous and cause this kind of problem. And I am saying that in the posted code there is no `option` I knew it was a global variable from your problem, not from your code.

Comment: So why there is no problem with other global variables (menuX, menuY) and it works well? There is variable 'option' in posted code. Example: 'If (button==3) {option =1}' But ok I will try to do this in other way

Comment: Is your button de-bounced?

Comment: @LukasThomsen yes. This is switch.

Comment: Global variables can work well, they just tend to cause errors, so you should avoid them.

Comment: @iharob thanks, i have just created this variable in [main()] and use as parameter in function like you said and it works.

Comment: @user3191398 I am glad, I hope you learned a valuable lesson about global variables.

Comment: @iharob did you consider the need that sometimes (in fact often) global var's need to be declared `volatile` to work properly and survive compiler optimisation. So declared global var's work superb to transfer information between different functions in different code blocks / compilation units

Comment: @MikeD They are good if you are lazy or not smart enough, but usually they will cause problems. Although somtimes, they are the best fit.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know function `init()` but let's asume that `menuX`, `menuY` are properly initialized there (otherwise they would be random). What we can see is that at least `menuChoice` is used in a different source code file than where it is declared ... this might be the case for other global variables, too (that's why they are declared global).

I suggest to declare these variables `volatile`, so that the compiler gets a hint that these variables may be changed outside the actual compilation unit and hences gets a bit more careful with optimisation, e.g.

```
volatile uint8_t menuX, menuY;
volatile uint8_t menuChoice, menu, option;
```

Alternatively try to completely switch off compiler optimisation (`-O0`)

[Further info](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_volatile)